# SQL query: Fetch Employee Name (i.e. FirstName space LastName), Department Name, Manager, City, StateProvinceCode, CountryRegionCode

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression, self-join

CONDITIONS:  Where city is 'New York'. If Manager is NULL then display 'CEO'.
I have shared the link of table structure.

[image: Table Structure/Schema Diagram]

I understand that I may be able to achieve this via sub-queries, CTE or a Self Join. But I am new to CTEs/Self Joins so need some help.

Trying something like below: But I am very confused how to do this.

```
WITH CTE EmployeeManager(

Select Concat(FirstName, ,LastName) as [Employee Name] 
FROM Contact C JOIN Employee E ON C.ContactID=E.ContactID
Where E.ManagerID IS NULL
UNION ALL
Select Concat(FirstName, ,LastName) as [Employee Name] 
FROM Contact C JOIN Employee E ON C.ContactID=E.ContactID
JOIN EmployeeManager EM ON E.ManagerID=EM.EmployeeID 
)

Select [Employee Name]  from EmployeeManager;
```

Not able to proceed further. Please help...

Comment: I can't see EmployeeManager in a schema. Could you provide an example in some online tool? http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php for example

Comment: You do not need to do CTEs, especially not recursive CTEs, since you only want the immediate manager, right ? You just need to do a self join, like ... FROM Employee Emps JOIN Employee Managers ON (Emps.ManagerId=Managers.EmployeeID), then you can refer to the employee's name as Emps.FirstName and Managers.FirstName for the managers

Comment: Also, you may need to use an OUTER join, to allow to use CEO for those with no manager, so ... FROM Employee Emps LEFT OUTER JOIN Emplyee Managers

Comment: And then use COALESCE for replacing the null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the below should work or point you in the right direction. I've assumed a couple of thing about you data:

1) Managers are found by looking up and ManagerID against EmployeeID in the Employee table

2) Employees in their history may have worked in more than one department and you are only looking for current employees so EndDate in EmployeeDepartmentHistory IS NULL

3) Employees may have multiple address stored so I pick the latest one by using a subquery

```
SELECT 
Concat(C.FirstName,' ',C.LastName) as [Employee Name],
D.[Department Name],
COALESCE(Concat(M.FirstName,' ',M.LastName),'CEO') as [Manager Name],
A.City,
SP.StateProvinceCode,
SP.CountryRegionCode

FROM Employee AS E
LEFT JOIN Contact AS C ON E.ContactID=C.ContactID
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS EDH ON EDH.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Department AS D ON D.DepartmentID=EDH.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN Employee AS Manager ON Manager.EmployeeID.=E.ManagerID
LEFT JOIN Contact AS M ON Manager.ContactID=M.ContactID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeID, AddressID, MAX(ModifiedDate) FROM [Employee Address] GROUP BY EmployeeID, AddressID) AS EA ON E.EmployeeID=EA.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Address AS A ON EA.AddressID=A.AddressID
LEFT JOIN StateProvince AS SP ON SP.StateProvinceID=A.StateProvinceID
WHERE EDH.EndDate IS NULL
AND A.City='New York'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your solution looks perfect. If possible, can you please explain why do we need self join on 2 tables (Employee Table and Contact Table)?

Comment: The first join employees to contact provides us the name of the employees, we then self join employees to employees to get the contactID for each employee's manager, and then we lookup this contactID in a new contact table to retrieve the name of each employee's manager. Does that help?

Comment: Happy to help @user8425592 would you be able to check this as the answer please? :)